# Using NP where gives "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous" error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to remove, from a np array, two values - 0 and 'Draw'.
But, I am receiving the below error message. I realize I could remove the values using index positions, but for a large array it would be tiresome. Is there a way to fit the np.where condition to achieve this?
I went through this answer, but couldn't understand. [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

```
Team_Names = np.delete(Team_Names, np.where(Team_Names == [0] or  Team_Names == ['Draw']))
```

[image: Team Names array]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what the array `Team_Names` is? is it an 1-D array or multidimensional? Normally you can not use `or` when you want to get the element-wise `or` of two arrays, instead you should use `|` operator.

Comment: Hi Woods, Thanks for your reply. I have added the print of Team_Names above. I replaced the or with | & am facing this error: 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'str''

Comment: Because `|` operator is prior to `==` operator, so `[0] | Team_Names` will be executed first when `Team_Names == [0] | Team_Names == ['Draw']` is being executed, thus `TypeError`  is raised because we can not use `|` operator between string objects and int objects. To solve this, add some parenthesis to change the priority of operaings: `(Team_Names == 0) | (Team_Names == 'Draw')`

Comment: @Woods, Thanks a ton. Understood.